Make all memory changes in one thread visible to all others with fence on writer thread
In C++11, I am doing an initialization of an object and then once done, I set a flag and call a completion handler(the whole initialization is done in async manner).
Below is a simplified version:
void Foo::initializeAsync(completion_handler h){
  initialize();
  m_inited = true;
  h();
}

Now the handler h, would spread work to multiple threads(part of a thread pool on top of boost io_service which is already started. h is just posting work to that thread pool) which call methods on same Foo object and each method has following:
void Foo:do_some_work() { // called from multiple thread
  CUSTOM_ASSERT(m_inited);
  //... do rest of work
}

I am wondering, how can i prevent the assert from failing in a multi-core setup(x86-64 and aarch64) because of memory visibility rules?
Would a simple memory fence in initialization like below would make sure the cache lines are updated across all cores before they access it?
void Foo::initializeAsync(completion_handler h){
  initialize();
  m_inited = true;
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst); // fence 
  h();
}


Note: I do not want to use an atomic_bool for m_inited as I do not want the cost of load given its updated only once in the lifetime of program.
Edit1: Updated to indicate that the threadpool is already started and the handler h is posting work to it after the manual fence.

It's extremely difficult to do lockless programming correctly. And if you succeed, you got some very hard to maintain code for the next guy.  You seem to imply there's a performance issue with atomics. But honestly speaking, does your program require this level of performance optimization?  Is it just the m_inited variable that needs to be checked, or is there other data initialized on the main thread that you want the worker thread to pick up?  What are you really trying to do?

It sounds like your threads are necessarily started (in or under h()) after initialize() is called, so the values set in initialize() are visible without any explicit synchronisation effort from you.  This is true for C++ Standard Library threading, and also under POSIX.  That's assuming "would spread work to multiple threads" means the trhreads are spawned in h(), rather than having e.g. a thread pool waiting to be passed the work... in that case you would need a fence and what you have would work, though just a release suffices.

"Now the handler h, would spread work to multiple threads which call methods on same Foo object and each method has following:": Is any synchronization implied in doing so? If yes, do you need any other synchronization? If no, then m_inited must be atomic to avoid a data race and undefined behavior. A fence after the write to m_inited can't prevent a data race if the read of m_inited can already happen before the fence.

Updated the description to indicate the threads are already running and just waiting for tasks from a queue(Boost's io_service ) which is where h posts.

There's likely sufficient serialization happening inside "spread work" part, passing the work over to the thread pool. That code likely locks mutexes, signals condition variables, and all that fun. There are fences galore in there. A thread pool implementation where "send the unit of work to the worker thread" doesn't synchronize with "start working on that unit" would be unusuable.
